# Can't seem to acces an element in a html

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying for over 3 hours to make my program open a page from the website [supremenewyork.com](https://www.supremenewyork.com/).

The lines of the HTML are in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BvR1.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrQhD.png) images.

What i would like to do is open the product by ingressing the colour (in this case Natural) and the name of the product (Shop Hooded Sweatshirt).

I've tried `find_elements_by_name`, `xpath` but they don't seem to work, and there is no class that's unique.

This is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

drive = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='../drivers/chromedriver')
drive.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all')

search = drive.find_element_by_link_text("sweatshirts")
search.click()
```

Comment: The code you shared here doesn't work? Have you checked the page source which your program/Selenium receives? IIRC Supreme (and similar brands) put a good amount of effort into stopping bots/scrapers from using their site, right?

Comment: Your executable path needs to be chromedriver.exe and you have backticks. With those fixes it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to click the sweatshirts tag and then get the values to check and wait for the page to load.

```
driver.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all')
search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "sweatshirts")))
search.click()
articles = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#container > li > div")))
for article in articles:
    name = article.find_element_by_css_selector("div.product-name > a")
    print(name.text)
    style = article.find_element_by_css_selector("div.product-style > a")
    print(style.text)
    #if name.text=='' and style.text=='':
        #name.click()
```